Pandas boxplots - styling props with colors not working
I would like to style all aspects of my boxplots via style sheets and apply the defined styles via plt.style.use("my_style"). So the goal is to "out source" all the styling attributes of the chart via code and define them inside the style.
Unfortunately not all colors are recognized. 
This is just an excerpt from the file:
### BoxPLots

boxplot.showmeans:   True
boxplot.showcaps:    True
boxplot.showbox:     True
boxplot.showfliers:  True
boxplot.meanline:    True
boxplot.showmeans:   True
boxplot.showcaps:    True
boxplot.showbox:     True
boxplot.showfliers:  True
boxplot.meanline:    True

# these color styles are parially applied 
boxplot.medianprops.color: "red"      # not applied
boxplot.medianprops.linestyle: solid  # applied
boxplot.meanprops.color: "yellow"     # applied
boxplot.meanprops.linestyle: dashed   # applied
boxplot.boxprops.color: 'red'         # not applied
boxplot.boxprops.linestyle: dotted    # applied

its getting applied by:
    df = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=['Values'])
    plt.style.use("my_style")
    bp = df.boxplot(column=['Values'],
                    capprops=dict(color='#ff5c00'),
                    flierprops=dict(marker='o', markeredgecolor='#fdfc60', markersize=10))

Result:
The meanline is shown and its color, as well as all linestyles are applied but neither the colors for the box nor the median.
The programmatically definitions like for capprops and flierprops are working.

The style sheet has some syntax errors. Some of the colors don't need to be specified with "" and are therefore ignored:
Try this:
### Custom BoxPlot Style

# General BoxPlot Settings
boxplot.showmeans: True
boxplot.showcaps: True
boxplot.showbox: True
boxplot.showfliers: True
boxplot.meanline: True

# Box (the main body of the boxplot)
boxplot.boxprops.color: red
boxplot.boxprops.linestyle: dotted

# Median Line
boxplot.medianprops.color: red
boxplot.medianprops.linestyle: solid

# Mean Line
boxplot.meanprops.color: yellow
boxplot.meanprops.linestyle: dashed

# Whiskers
boxplot.whiskerprops.color: “#ff5c00”  # Orange color in hexadecimal

# Fliers (Outliers)
boxplot.flierprops.marker: o
boxplot.flierprops.markeredgecolor: “#fdfc60” # Light yellow in hexadecimal
boxplot.flierprops.markersize: 10


Hi DanieL, this  boxplot.whiskerprops.color: #ff5c00  # Orange color in hexadecimal
won't work without any quotes:
boxplot.whiskerprops.color: "#ff5c00"  # Orange color in hexadecimal
